# Possible to connect to storage account when connected to openvpn vm in subnet

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-network, azure-storage-account

I have an azure vnet, that contains subnet A and subnet B.

Subnet A contains SQL server with a private endpoint, also a VM running openvpn. When I connect to the vpn from my local machine, I can connect to SQL server management studio.

Subnet B contains a storage account again with a private endpoint.

I thought if I connected to the vpn from my local machine, I would also be able to connect to the storage account using the storage account name and key.

However it fails to connect :(

I haven't locked down the subnets in anyway, and figured once I was inside the vnet via the openvpn connection I'd be in (able to connect to storage account in subnet B)

Any tips would be awesome... I'm much more developer that network engineer so please dumb it down for me.

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I needed to add subnet B here in the VPN settings of OpenVPN :)

[image: Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be given access (one per line):]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try some basic ping tests when connected to the OpenVPN.

Does the storage account private IP replay to ping?

Also, you could be having routing issues. Maybe check if your local workstation has routes to Subnet B when connected to OpenVPN.

Azure automatically creates system routes and assigns the routes to each subnet in a virtual network but maybe you must manually add them to OpenVPN.

It is also worth to check the storage account firewall.

In a nutshell, it could be a list of things :)